# Pass values of record from Salesforce to Servicenow using e.force:navigateToURL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, forcenavigatetourl

When doing this even the Status of the Case should be changed to "Closed."
So we have created a Apex Controller where we are changing the status of the case and called it in the Lightning Component.

Apex Controller:

```
public class CaseServiceNowController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Case GetCaseValues(String recordId){

        case cs = [select Id, Federation_ID__c, Link__c FROM Case where id=:recordId];
        case cupd = new case();
        cupd.status = 'closed';
        cupd.id = cs.id;          
        update cupd;
        return cupd;        
    }

}
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" controller = "CaseServiceNowController" >

    <!-- Include Static Resources - if any -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />    
    <!--aura:attribute name = "url" type ="String"/-->
    <aura:attribute name= "CaseObj" type = "Case" default="{
        'sobjectType': 'Case','Federation_ID__c' : '','Link__c' : ''}"/>


</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component,event,helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.GetCaseValues");
        var a = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({ recordId : a });
        alert("+++++++++++++++" +a);
        // Create a callback that is executed after 
        // the server-side action returns
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            // alert("+++++" +response);
            var state = response.getState();
            alert("------------------" + state);
            // alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());            
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //    var sample = JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue());
              //  alert("dddddddddd" +sample);
              var sample2 = JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue());
                alert("------+++++" +sample2);
 var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                var urlAttribute = sample2.Federation_ID__c +'&sysparm_quotelink='+ sample2.Link__c;
                alert("------------------" +urlAttribute);
                urlEvent.setParams({
                    "url": 'https://testrackspace.service-now.com/rack_sp?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=4bb14bc2c84f4e0087fd91e81c4cff48&&sysparm_salesrep=' + urlAttribute
                });
                urlEvent.fire();                                                
            }                        
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
}).
```

The issue here is, `response.getReturnValue()` is returning values but we're not able to associate it with the URL. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: You said "getReturnValue()" is returning values...what does the URL look like after you concatenate it in "setParams"? Does it look as expected? Could you copy and past that from the debug logs and get directed to where you're trying to go?

Comment: `sample2` is `Sting` type after you use `JSON.stringify` ,  you append the `Federation_ID__c ` property  by using `.` notation which is wrong. if you want exact solution for your issue, please post what type you got  for `response.getReturnValue()` and what is your expected `URL`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to JSON stringify the object to get fields off off of the case object you are passing back since it is a standard sobject

```
({
doInit : function(component,event,helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.GetCaseValues");
    var a = component.get("v.recordId");
    action.setParams({ recordId : a });
    // Create a callback that is executed after 
    // the server-side action returns
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();          
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var case = response.getReturnValue();
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        var urlAttribute = case.Federation_ID__c +'&sysparm_quotelink='+ case.Link__c;
        var urlStr = 'https://testrackspace.service-now.com/rack_sp?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=4bb14bc2c84f4e0087fd91e81c4cff48&&sysparm_salesrep=' + urlAttribute;
                urlEvent.setParams({
                    "url": urlStr
                });
                urlEvent.fire();                                                
            }                        
        });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Comment: You should also add error handing if the state is not 'SUCCESS'